# Export Slides from Powerpoint To HTML5 File

Tags: c#, html, export, powerpoint

I'm looking for a way to export each slide of a PowerPoint file as a html file.

I've tried many way:

```
using Powerpoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

PowerPoint.Application app = new Powerpoint.Application();
PowerPoint.Presentation pres = app.presentation.Open(filepath+"filename.ppt", MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

//Trying to export presentation as Html
pres.SaveAs(filepath+"filename.html", PowerPoint.PpSaveAsHtml, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

//Trying to export each Slide as image. Unfortunately don't export as html
int i = 0;
foreach (PowerPoint.Slide slide in press.Slide){
    i+=1;
    String oPath = filepath+"filename_"+i+".jpg";
    slide.Export(oPath, "jpg", 1024, 768);
}

pres.Close();
App.Quit();
```

Can I programmatically export each slides as a simple html file that keeps the animations.

Comment: Why would an HTML file which contains animations be *simple*?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your question. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: What features of HTML lead you to believe that PowerPoint style animations would be simple to implement with it?

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use a converter to do it. SlideGo is a freeware that has an option to convert each slide to one HTML file with all animations retained. Actually it even better than many commercial tools.